# Functional generation of ipv4 subnetmask dotted binary in python

Tags: python, functional-programming, ip, list-comprehension

I got the following problem:
The number of set bits in an ipv4 subnetmask is given
and I coded very iteratively

```
 def calculateSnmFromNBits(self):
    s = ""
    for i in xrange(35):
        if i + 1 % 9 == 0:
            s += '.'
            if i < self.nBits:
                self.nBits += 1
        elif i < self.nBits:
           s += '1'
        else:
           s += '0'
    return s
```

I tried a list comprehension but I'd need an elif to insert the dots
so I can only do

```
['1' if i < nBits else '0' for i in xrange(32)] #missing the dots
```

Thank You

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: yes my question is how to integrate the dots in an oneliner sry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nBits=27
print '.'.join((('1'*nBits+'0'*(32-nBits))[i:i+8]) for i in (0,8,16,24))
```

Result:

```
11111111.11111111.11111111.11100000
```

Or,

```
print '.'.join(str(((0xFFFFFFFF& (~((1<<(32-nBits))-1)))>>(i*8))&255) for i in range(3,-1,-1))
255.255.255.224
```

Or,

```
import ipaddress
print(str(ipaddress.ip_network('0.0.0.0/%s'%nBits).netmask))
```